# java - servlets - set encoding and session in base class?

Tags: java, session, inheritance, encoding, servlet-3.0

I am crawling through a servlet site and in almost every doPost I encounter code like this :

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // set encoding to UTF-8
    if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null)
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    // TODO : this may be needed in doGet too ?????????
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    // check if session exists
    boolean sessionExists = request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (!sessionExists)
        session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1000);

    // if session does not exist we create it
    ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
    Integer numSessions = (Integer) context
            .getAttribute("numberOfSessions");
    if (numSessions == null)
        context.setAttribute("numberOfSessions", 1);
    else if (!sessionExists)
        context.setAttribute("numberOfSessions", ++numSessions);
}
```

Would it be a good idea to create a BaseController class and move this code there - and should I move it in the init() method or in the doPost() - and then call `super.doPost` ? Also there are lines like `session.setAttribute("photo", photo);` in some of the servlets. Would it then be a good idea to have a `session` field in the BaseController - which if I understand things correctly should be volatile.

I am new to all this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move setting the request character encoding to a helper method and call it from  doPost. Also check if your code behaved correctly in case that the encoding is set to something else than utf-8.

On the other hand, the session stuff is a bit weird. If you want to keep track of the number of sessions, remove all that and use javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener. It is more elegant and you will have your code in a single place.

If you need to keep track of variables that belong to a session, keep using the HttpSession class, do not save them in a field in the controller.

Comment: Thanks - I meant to have an `HttpSession volatile session;` field in the BaseController class - and call `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` in the BaseController's doPost. It looks more elegant this way - but maybe not a good idea in servlets programming ? I have no clue (yet) what is the `numberOfSessions` for - it is not my code - I'll look into javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener.

Comment: You don't need to have the session as a field in your controller, the servlet container takes care of that.

Comment: It does but does not provide a field - only a method (`getSession()`). So the idea is to have all initializations take place in the doPost or init() of BaseController.

Comment: You can initialize attributes inside the session using the HttpSessionListener mentioned before.

Comment: Tried the HttpSessionListener - unfortunately apparently the Listener is not triggered on redeploy - have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551788/java-servlets-sessions-count-issues-on-redeploying)

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseController extends HttpServlet {

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    }
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); [...]

    doService(request, response);
}

protected abstract void doService(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception, Error;
```

}

And then you have to extend the BaseContoller class, and implement just the doService (or whatever) method.

Comment: Could you elaborate ? Probably that is what I am thinking to do (BaseController  being the "template").

Comment: Thanks - apparently Listeners and Filters is the way to go. This service method is nice though - should be smth like : `//set encoding; super.service(req, resp);`